# Norm of $T:(C[0,1],||.||_{\infty})\to \mathbb R,$ $T(f)=\int_0^1tf(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $C[0,1]$ denote the set of all  continious real valued function  on the interval $[0,1]$ and $T:(C[0,1],||.||_{\infty})\to \mathbb R$ be defined by $T(f)=\int_0^1tf(t)$ 
>    for all $f \in C[0,1]$. Then find $||T||$?

**My attempt:**

i take  constant function $f(t)=1$   i got $||T||=1$.

is its true ???

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: How did you get $\|T\| = 1 $ using $f=1$??? $Tf = {1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, note that

$\vert T(f) \vert = \left \vert \displaystyle \int_0^1 tf(t) \; dt \right \vert \le \displaystyle \int_0^1 t \vert f(t) \vert \; dt \le \displaystyle \int_0^1 t \Vert f \Vert_\infty \; dt = \Vert f \Vert_\infty \int_0^1 t \; dt = \dfrac{1}{2} \Vert f \Vert_\infty, \tag 1$

which shows that

$\Vert T \Vert \le \dfrac{1}{2}; \tag 2$

now take

$f(t) = 1, \tag 3$

and find that

$\vert T(1) \vert = \left \vert \displaystyle \int_0^1 t \; dt \right \vert = \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \Vert 1 \Vert_\infty, \tag 4$

which precludes the possibility that

$\Vert T \Vert < \dfrac{1}{2} \tag 5$

since this would imply

$\vert T(1) \vert \le \Vert T \Vert \Vert 1 \Vert_\infty < \dfrac{1}{2} \Vert 1 \Vert_\infty, \tag 6$

contradicting (4).  Therefore,

thus

$\Vert T \Vert = \dfrac{1}{2}. \tag 7$

Answer (score 2):

For any $f\in C[0, 1]$, we have
$$
|T(f)| = \Big|\int_{0}^{1}tf(t)dt\Big| \leq \int_{0}^{1}t |f(t)|dt \leq ||f||_{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}tdt = \frac{1}{2}||f||_{\infty}
$$
so $||T||\leq 1/2$, and we have $||T||\geq 1/2$ by taking $f \equiv 1$.